# Casper CLI Options not handling white spaces on Windows

Tags: windows, terminal, phantomjs, casperjs

On `Terminal` of **Mac**, if I enter in the command

```
casperjs test.js --name="Bashir Osman"
```

it will return

```
{
    "casper-path": "/Users/casperjs",
    "cli": true,
    "name": "Bashir Osman"
}
```

However, on **Windows** (using the same command)

```
casperjs test.js --name="Bashir Osman"
```

it will return

```
{
    "casper-path": "C:\\Users\\casperjs",
    "cli": true,
    "name": "Bashir"
}
```

[found an issue on github, but it seems unrelated](https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/issues/269)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On windows, you'll need multiple double quotes.

change

```
casperjs test.js --name="Bashir Osman"
```

to

```
casperjs test.js --name="""Bashir Osman"""
```

Comment: YES - and this holds true, even when calling without a named parameter: `call casperjs.exe test.js """Bashir Osman"""`